# Do I still need gctools with Ruby 2.2 even though its garbage collection has been upgraded?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, garbage-collection, ruby-2.2

I am upgrading my app to use Ruby 2.2, and was going to remove gctools since I think it specifically supports Ruby 2.1's garbage collection. Any reason I should keep it?

Comment: "Any reason I should keep it around?" That depends. Was there any reason you wanted it in the first place? The project's github page says it is "built on new apis and events offered in ruby 2.1", which to me means that it will likely work with any version of Ruby >2.1

Comment: It does seem to work, but since GC was revised heavily, didn't know if it became redundant.  Always looking to remove as much cruff when possible, and frankly this level of the system is a bit beyond my skills.  Thought maybe there was a gctools expert that could drop a thought or two and give so ideas on how it is still relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after further review, it seems it is unnecessary according to the maintainer of gctools, Aman Gupta (tmm1):

> ["oobgc is unnecessary in Ruby 2.2, since it includes an incremental
>   GC (RIncGC) and will not pause the world for a long
>   time."](https://github.com/tmm1/gctools/issues/11)

So, in case anyone else is seeing this error,

```
listen loop error: unknown key: old_object (ArgumentError)
```

try pulling gctools out.

Comment: Nice. Deleting my answer then.

Comment: Thanks for the effort though Agis.  This question will be irrelevant soon anyway (hopefully).  There is a pull request to add it to the README.